# How to create a nameable MIDI port with Universal Windows Platform?

Tags: c#, uwp, midi, midi-interface

How to create a nameable MIDI port with Universal Windows Platform (Anniversary Update on Windows 10)?

It seems that https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/09/21/midi-enhancements-in-windows-10/#r5BB7v0LGxqUvY4g.97 does not give an answer on that topic.

Comment: Have you already known how to create a MIDI port? Did you want to specially know how to create a 'nameable' MIDI port? What `nameable` here specially mean? Why you need 'nameable'?

Comment: No, I don't know how to create a MIDI port using Universal Windows Platform. _Nameable_ means that I can set a name which appears in other prgrams that needs a MIDI port.